# Dante SOCKS5 proxy server not working on ipv6

Tags: socks5-proxy

During testing and entering this command

```
curl -x socks5://<user>:<pass>@<ip>:<port> ifconfig.co
```

It returns an error message of

```
Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to <ip address v6>
```

When we disable the ipv6, thats the time the curl testing works but thats not the right way. Tried to apply this tutorial but still got no luck

http://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/ipv6.html

=============================================================

dante.conf

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: enp0s3 port = 1080
external: enp0s3
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

Comment: Do you have a public routable IPv6 on both hosts?

Comment: I can see inet and inet6 ip addresses from enp0s3 network interface when I run the ifconfig -a command. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As from https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/config/ipv6.html

> Changes to sockd.conf in an IPv4-only usage scenarios are only
> necessary if either of Dante's internal or external interface
> addresses are specified in sockd.conf using interfacenames (e.g.,
> external: eth0) or hostnames (e.g., internal: dante-int.example.com),
> and these interfacenames or hostnames now, or possibly in the future,
> will contain IPv6 addresses.
>
> The Dante server will by default use all addresses found on an
> internal interface if the interface is specified by it's name (rather
> than by one of its IP-addresses). If the interface has one or more
> IPv6 addresses, this will result in the Dante server also using the
> IPv6 addresses.

Check if the interface `enp0s3` has assigned ipv6 address and if yes then dante is trying to use it. With that in mind replacing the `enp03s` with the ipv4 address should fix this.

Example:

```
internal: 10.2.4.6 port = 1080
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Dante server to accept requests on both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, it is necessary to specify either a network interface that has both types of addresses as an argument to the internal sockd.conf keyword, or specify the keyword multiple times with different addresses. For example:

```
#accept SOCKS requests on 10.0.0.1 (IPv4) and fc00::01 (IPv6)
internal: 10.0.0.1 port = 1080
internal: fc00::1  port = 1080
```

Dante's config file will also need rules for both address types.

```
#accept connections from any IPv4 client
client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
```

The above is an example of a rule for IPv4 addresses that will allow any IPv4 client to connect to the Dante server. An equivalent rule for IPv6 can look like the following:

```
#accept connections from any IPv6 client
client pass {
        from: ::/0 to: ::/0
}
```

Both of the above rules match only one address type, the first only IPv4, the second only IPv6. To add a rule that accepts any address, regardless of address family, the following special Dante-specific address syntax can be used (0/0):

```
#accept connections from any client
client pass {
        from: 0/0 to: 0/0
}
```